# Trying to recreate my console.log objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, typescript

I have a var that contains 4 objects that I see when I log it out in the console. But I have been trying to create the structure of this return variable (I want to sort it but first want to recreate the structure), but are failing at the last hurdle.

This is what the console puts out on **original** variable: `[Object, Object, Object, Object]`

This is what I get with **created** variable: `[Object]`

Here is my code to try and re-create it:

```
this.obj =      [{items:[{code:'bravo',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-01',pos:'up'},
                             {code:'alpha',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-02',pos:'down'}],
                     color:'blue'}],
                    [{items:[{code:'bravo',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-01',pos:'up'},
                             {code:'alpha',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-02',pos:'down'}],
                     color:'green'}],
                    [{items:[{code:'bravo',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-01',pos:'up'},
                             {code:'alpha',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-02',pos:'down'}],
                     color:'red'}],
                    [{items:[{code:'bravo',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-01',pos:'up'},
                             {code:'alpha',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-02',pos:'down'}],
                     color:'yellow'}]
                    ;
```

The first objects of both **original** and **created** are identical, but why does it not see my other three objects? If I add two `[]` around my code, it's sees all four, but then they have changed to arrays instead of objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working for anyone who wants to know:

```
this.obj =      [{0:{items:[{code:'bravo',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-01',pos:'up'},
                         {code:'alpha',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-02',pos:'down'}],
                 color:'blue'}},
                {1:{items:[{code:'bravo',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-01',pos:'up'},
                         {code:'alpha',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-02',pos:'down'}],
                 color:'green'}},
                {2:{items:[{code:'bravo',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-01',pos:'up'},
                         {code:'alpha',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-02',pos:'down'}],
                 color:'red'}},
                {3:{items:[{code:'bravo',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-01',pos:'up'},
                         {code:'alpha',color:'blue',date:'2017-01-02',pos:'down'}],
                 color:'yellow'}}]
                ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems broken, if you order it in a **readable** way then it's clear:

```
var obj = [
    {
        items: [{
            code: 'bravo', color: 'blue', date: '2017-01-01', pos: 'up'
        }, {
            code: 'alpha', color: 'blue', date: '2017-01-02', pos: 'down'
        }],
        color: 'blue'
    }] // <=== the array ends here, but now you have this:
    , [{ items: [{ ...
```

The compiler then does this:

```
var obj = [
    {
        items: [{
                code: 'bravo', color: 'blue', date: '2017-01-01', pos: 'up'
            }, {
                code: 'alpha', color: 'blue', date: '2017-01-02', pos: 'down'
            }],
        color: 'blue'
    }
], _a = (void 0)[0], _b = ....
```

As you can see it creates another variable (`_a`) to store the other data.

Comment: That is what I got as well, which is why I said that when I add extra brackets around the code to change it form `[a,b],[c,d]` to `[[a,b],[c,d]]` I get all four objects, but they are now not objects but arrays: `[Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1]]` instead of `[Object, Object, Object, Object]`. So how do you think I would  include the other 3 objects, without turning them into arrays?